# ArrayList<Double> to double[] with 300 million entries

Tags: java, memory, median

I'm using a java program to get some data from a DB. I then calculate some numbers and start storing them in an array. The machine I'm using has 4 gigs of RAM. Now, I don't know how many numbers there will be in advance, so I use an `ArrayList<Double>.` But I do know there will be roughly `300 million numbers.`

So, since one double is 8 bytes a rough estimate of the memory this array will consume is 2.4 gigs (probably more because of the overheads of an ArrayList). After this, I want to calculate the median of this array and am using the `org.apache.commons.math3.stat.descriptive.rank.Median` library which takes as input a `double[]` array. *So, I need to convert the `ArrayList<Double>` to `double[]`*.

I did see many questions where this is raised and they all mention there is no way around looping through the entire array. Now this is fine, but since they also maintain both objects in memory, this brings my memory requirements up to 4.8 gigs. Now we have a problem since the total RAM available us 4 gigs.

First of all, is my suspicion that the program will at some point give me a memory error correct (it is currently running)? And if so, how can I calculate the median without having to allocate double the memory? I want to avoid sorting the array as calculating the median is O(n).

Comment: Write a code to show what are you doing.

Comment: If the data is in the DB, why aren't you using the DB to perform the calculation?  You're talking about retrieving 300 million rows from a query?  What DB are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is even worse than you realize, because `ArrayList<Double>` is much less efficient than 8 bytes per entry. Each entry is actually an object, to which the `ArrayList` keeps an array of references. A `Double` object is probably about 12 bytes (4 bytes for some kind of type identifier, 8 bytes for the `double` itself), and the reference to it adds another 4, bringing the total up to 16 bytes per entry, even excluding overhead for memory management and such.

If the constraints were a little wider, you could implement your own `DoubleArray` that is backed by a `double[]` but knows how to resize itself. However, the resizing means you'll have to keep a copy of both the old and the new array in memory at the same time, also blowing your memory limit.

That still leaves a few options though:

- Loop through the input twice; once to count the entries, once to read them into a right-sized `double[]`. It depends on the nature of your input whether this is possible, of course.
- Make some assumption on the maximum input size (perhaps user-configurable), and allocate a `double[]` up front that is this fixed size. Use only the part of it that's filled.
- Use `float` instead of `double` to cut memory requirements in half, at the expense of some precision.
- Rethink your algorithm to avoid holding everything in memory at once.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. so, will a double[] array require no more than 8*size_of_array memory or is some overhead involved with that as well?

Comment: double[] does not have any per-element overhead

Answer (score 2):

There are many open source libraries that create dynamic arrays for primitives. One of these:
http://trove.starlight-systems.com/

Answer (score 1):

The Median value is the value at the middle of a sorted list. So you don't have to use a second array, you can just do:

```
Collections.sort(myArray);
final double median = myArray.get(myArray.size() / 2);
```

And since you get that data from a DB anyways, you could just tell the DB to give you the median instead of doing it in Java, which will save all the time (and memory) for transmitting the data as well.

Comment: Yeah, but Collections.sort() might decide to use mergesort which will require double the memory and throw an error (right?) Or will it know to use quicksort given the size of the array? I can't use sql directly as I do some processing on the data that requires multiple loops.

Comment: Collections.sort() also does not get you far because of the Double boxing overhead. If you decide to go for O(n log n), over-allocate and then use the 3 parameter variant of Arrays.sort(): http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree, use Trove4j `TDoubleArrayList` class (see [javadoc](http://trove4j.sourceforge.net/javadocs/gnu/trove/list/array/TDoubleArrayList.html)) to store double or `TFloatArrayList` for float. And by combining previous answers, we gets :

```
// guess initialcapacity to remove requirement for resizing
TDoubleArrayList data = new TDoubleArrayList(initialcapacity);
// fill data
data.sort();
double median = data.get(data.size()/2);
```